# How to run dotnet Core console application that shows the console window or not based on argument parameters?

Tags: c#, .net-core, console-application, avaloniaui

I have a single dotnet-core GUI application that depending on the argument parameters it may show only the GUI interface (done with Avalonia framework) or if it receives some special arguments then it should work in console-mode and log into the console without showing the GUI.
If I use `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`, then the GUI shows fine but the app will never log into the console (for example when using `Console.WriteLine("some-text")`).
This means I need to configure the csproj with `<OutputType>Exe</OutputType>` in order to be able to log into the console anything, the problem is that when running in GUI mode, along with the GUI application window, another console window pops up which I want to hide to show only the GUI.

In dotnet full-framework 4.X I was able to create WPF apps that did this dual console/gui mode in 1 exe.
A possible solution would be if I could make the console window to be hidden when running in GUI mode, or maybe Avalonia-UI/dotnet-core has some other way to do this.
Does anyone knows how to this?

**UPDATE:** Here are some clarifications:
The app has 2 modes:

- **GUI Mode**: if you just double click on the "App.exe" (runs with no args parameters) then the GUI should appear (and only the GUI, not the GUI plus another console window as it currently happens). This would be usually done by setting the csproj as `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>`, but that makes the `Console.Write` function not to work when run in the following `Console Mode`.
- **Console Mode**: if an advanced user is trying to use some of the app functions from the console automate something, then the app should behave like a console application, with all the features one would expect like `app.exe -h` to show the available commands, `app.exe -v` to show the version, etc. This means that it is not OK to show some hand-made GUI window displaying the output text or log anywhere else like into a file.

It could be done in 2 separate executable files, but some people like me find some beauty in applications that are just a simple app.exe file.
There are many examples of this dual behavior, like <s>VisualStudio's `devenv.exe` or</s> [Nirsoft](https://www.nirsoft.net/) applications.

Comment: I don't think I understand this question. It sounds like you want to output some text to a window that nobody will be able to see. Is that right? What is the point?

Comment: If I understand, you would like to show the GUI or the Console depending on the parameters your app receives. If so, why don't you use e method "LogToConsole" that writes in the Console.WriteLine if you're in the Console mode and that does nothing if you're in the GUI mode?

Comment: Are you only interested in the console just for logging information? If so then it's probably easier just to log to a file instead.

Comment: @JohnWu: When it runs as GUI it doesn't write to the console, and the console window should not be shown. But when it runs as ConsoleMode, then it shouldnt show the GUI and just write to the console. The problem is I can't find a way to control the console window visibility during runtime.
If I set the csproj as `WinExe` then it works well for the GUI mode and not for ConsoleMode (because it will not send anything to the console).
If I set the csproj as `Exe` then it works well for ConsoleMode, but not for GUI mode (because then it will open 2 windows: 1 with the GUI, and a console window)

Comment: "Like VisualStudio's `devenv.exe`" - you mean the pair of `devenv.com` and `devenv.exe`, the former of which is a console application and is what you get if you run `devenv` at the command line, and the latter of which is a windows GUI application? They may not be implemented as you thought they were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get you right you want to start the console on special parameter and WinForms application on the other hand.

First you have to set

```
<DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
```

In your project file. [See documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/windows-forms/5.0/automatically-infer-winexe-output-type)

Try to set the `<OutputType>` back to `Exe` and add this to your *Program > Main*:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    ///  The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        IntPtr h = GetConsoleWindow();

        // switch here to show or not show console window
        ShowWindow(h, 0);
        // ShowWindow(h, 1);

        Application.SetHighDpiMode(HighDpiMode.SystemAware);
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        // Hide your WinForms application manually if parameter is set
        var startup = new MainFormStartup();
        Application.Run(startup.CreateForm<MainWindow>());
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
}
```

I tried this locally with

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <PropertyGroup>
      <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
      <TargetFramework>net5.0-windows</TargetFramework>
      <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
      <DisableWinExeOutputInference>true</DisableWinExeOutputInference>
   </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

But to be honest in my optinion you should have two exe files compiled with a shared library to accomplish a console exe file and a UI-exe file, fe.:

yourcode.csproj (Your Businesslogic)

- yourapp-console.csproj (Console Application: with a reference to yourcode.csproj)
- yourapp-ui.csproj (WinForms Application: with a reference to yourcode.csproj)

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot for the response! I think you understood the question perfectly.

Comment: The solution however is not completely perfect, it has some gotchas:

- With the `ShowWindow()` method used to hide the console, if you try to open the app.exe in GUI mode from the command line, it will hide your existing terminal window from which you are invoking the `.\App.exe` ! (tested in windows 10 using a PowerShell 7.1 terminal)

- Also when double clicking in the `App.exe` to open the GUI, the console window flashes for a split second even if it's the at 1st line, ideally it wouldn't appear at all.

Comment: Another major issue would be that even if it is a GUI app, it doesn't mean I'm using a windows only framework like WinForms or WPF. I'm using [Avalonia-UI](https://avaloniaui.net/), which is cross platform (windows/Mac/Linux), but this solution only works for windows.

Comment: @Lorazo Sorry for that but it was the only option I have found by using one single compilation. This is why I have added the imo better solution to compile to two different exe files with are shared codebase.

Comment: Hi @Lazaro did you find any solution for this avalonia hybrid situation?

Comment: I ended up with a single App.exe, but I couldn't make the console show text output to the terminal. [Here](https://github.com/LazaroOnline/AwsCredentialManager/blob/master/src/AwsCredentialManager/Program.cs) is an example:

csproj: `<OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>` 

program.cs:
`public static void Main(string[] args) { if (args...) {  doConsoleStuff(); } else BuildAvaloniaApp().StartWithClassicDesktopLifetime(args);`